# Difficulty to understand SQLite exists and its subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, exists

Assume there is one table called Temp, its schema and data are listed blow

Table Temp :

```
A         B       
----      ----

1         1        # Row 1 
1         5        # Row 2 
2         2        # Row 3
```

SQLite Query :

```
1) DELETE FROM Temp WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Temp AS IL2 WHERE Temp.A = IL2.A AND Temp.B = 1 AND IL2.B = 5)
2) DELETE FROM Temp WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Temp AS IL2 WHERE Temp.A = IL2.A AND Temp.B = 5 AND IL2.B = 1)
```

Question 1)
What is the meaning of "Temp.A = IL2.A"?
IL2 is alias of Temp, it compares to itself? I get lost here.

Question 2)
Query 1 and 2 deletes Row 1 and 2 by experiment, respectively. 
It seems to me that the return value of the sub-query "(SELECT 1 FROM Temp AS IL2 WHERE Temp.A = IL2.A AND Temp.B = 5 AND IL2.B = 1)" is controlled by the value of "IL2.B". I thought this sub-query return both Row 2 and Row 3.

Answer (score 2):

The delete statements look for a record with the same A, but the other B (1 vs. 5) in the same table. In order to do this a table alias (IL2) is needed to be able to distinguish between the one record and the other. The queries are a little obfuscated, though. Some criteria is hidden in the subquery where it not really belongs. Better would be:

```
delete from temp 
where b = 1 
and exists (select 1 from temp as il2 where il2.a = temp.a and il2.b = 5);

delete from temp 
where b = 5 
and exists (select 1 from temp as il2 where il2.a = temp.a and il2.b = 1);
```

A side remark: The second statement will not find (and hence delete) anything of course, because all b1 for which a b5 exists are already deleted then. In order to circumvent this and delete both records, i.e. both the b1 and b5, combine the two statements:

```
delete from temp
where b in (1,5)
and exists
(
  select *
  from temp other
  where other.b in (1,5)
    and other.a =  temp.a
    and other.b <> temp.b
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your re-factor Sql query.

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE EXISTS` means that all Rows will be deleted, where the Subquery `(SELECT 1 FROM Temp AS IL2 WHERE Temp.A = IL2.A AND Temp.B = 1 AND IL2.B = 5)` gets more than 0 results.

So look at the subquery. Basically it selects all values from temp a second time.

- `DELETE FROM Temp` -> First time (referenced as `Temp`)
- `SELECT 1 FROM temo AS IL2` -> Second time (referenced as `IL2`)

Now the subquery has its own where clause, in which both tables (`Temp` and `IL2`) are compared:

- In Temp and IL2, `A` has to be equal
- in Temp, B has to 1
- in IL2, B has to be 5

There are only 2 rows, where those clauses are true (and therefore returned): Row 1 and Row 2.

Comment: Thank you. I have the same idea as you for sub-query (Row 1 and Row 2 will return), but the experiment showed that only Row 1 is return for "(SELECT 1 FROM Temp AS IL2 WHERE Temp.A = IL2.A AND Temp.B = 1 AND IL2.B = 5)", which I do understand.

Comment: @Zhongkun Ma: The first statement returns row #1, because its B is 1 and there exists a record with the same A and with B = 5 in the table. The second statement returns row #2, because its B is 5 and there exists a record with the same A and with B = 1 in the table (provided, you didn't run the first statement already and deleted that record). It shouldn't be confusing you that the same table is queried twice. Maybe it helps to imagine there really *is* another table named IL2 with exactly the same data.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: I think I get it, but one thing to confirm. "(select 1 from Temp)" indicates the result is selected from Temp table and "Temp.B = 1" indicates the select result's B field in Table Temp  has to be 1. Am I correct?

Comment: @Zhongkun Ma: I've written an additional answer to explain the whole process step by step.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: I would like to thank you from my heart. This is super clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer explaining step by step what happens in the query. Let's take query #2:

```
DELETE FROM Temp 
WHERE EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 
  FROM Temp AS IL2 
  WHERE Temp.A = IL2.A 
    AND Temp.B = 5 
    AND IL2.B = 1
);
```

This statement is supposed to find records in table Temp and delete them. So let's start with the first record and see if it matches the criteria given in the where clause:

row #1: A=1, B=1

We are looking for existence in the same table, which we call IL2 (just as if it were a different table). So whenever we refer to the just-read record which we may want to delete or not, we use the qualifier Temp, and we read the table IL2 record for record in order to compare them with the Temp record. So let's look if we find a match:

```
A | B |  Temp.A = IL2.A?               | Temp.B = 5?       | IL2.B = 1? 
--+---+--------------------------------+-------------------+------------
1 | 1 |  Yes, both records have A=1.   | No, Temp.B is 1.  | Yes.
1 | 5 |  Yes, both records have A=1.   | No, Temp.B is 1.  | No, it's 5.
2 | 2 |  No, Temp.A is 1, IL2.A is 2.  | No, Temp.B is 1.  | No, it's 2.
```

As you see, `Temp.B = 5`? is always false (and would always be true, ich we looked at the second record row #2 instead), because although the criteria is in the EXISTS subquery, it really refers to the record that stands trial. This is why I recommended to move this criterion outside the EXISTS clause for readability. This query is 100% equivalent, but easier to read:

```
DELETE FROM Temp 
WHERE B = 5 
AND EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 
  FROM Temp AS IL2 
  WHERE IL2.A = Temp.A
    AND IL2.B = 1
);
```

Let's now look at this query instead. Again we read the first row from Temp. B is 1, so `WHERE B = 5` is not matched. The criteria is not met, the record will not get deleted.

Next record (row #2). B = 5. Okay, so let's look into the exists clause and check again record for record:

```
A | B |  Temp.A = IL2.A?               | IL2.B = 1? 
--+---+--------------------------------+------------
1 | 1 |  Yes, both records have A=1.   | Yes.
1 | 5 |  Yes, both records have A=1.   | No, it's 5.
2 | 2 |  No, Temp.A is 1, IL2.A is 2.  | No, it's 2.
```

Aha. The first record matches, so the EXISTS criteria is met. (The DBMS has to find at least one match. Once it found a match, it doesn't have to read the remaining records. So we could have stopped, after having found row #1 as a match.) All criteria is TRUE; the investigated Temp record (row #2) will get deleted.

Now to the last record. B is 2, so `WHERE B = 5` is not matched. The criteria is not met, the record will not get deleted.

I hope this clarifies how EXISTS works. (As to the "selected" data: it doesn't matter what you select in EXISTS; these three all work the same: `where exists (select 1 from ...)`, `where exists (select * from ...)`, `where exists (select 'yes, there exists a row' from ...)`.)